How to search through multiple tables using Postgres Full Text Search and GIN index in Django
models.py
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField


class FilmTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Film(models.Model):
    film_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(FilmTag, null=True, blank=True)

    vector_column = SearchVectorField(null=True)  # new field

    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join(['film_id=' + str(self.film_id), 'title=' + self.title, 'description=' + self.description])

    class Meta:
        indexes = (GinIndex(fields=["vector_column"]),)  # add index

0002_migration
# Generated by Django 5.0.4 on 2024-04-03 19:41

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("app", "0002_film_vector_column_film_app_film_vector__2213d6_gin"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql='''
              CREATE TRIGGER vector_column_trigger
              BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF title, description, vector_column
              ON app_film
              FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
              tsvector_update_trigger(
                vector_column, 'pg_catalog.english', title, description
              );

              UPDATE app_film SET vector_column = NULL;
            ''',

            reverse_sql='''
              DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS vector_column_trigger
              ON film;
            '''
        ),
    ]

I'd like to also search by tags using Postgres Full Text Search, so if i put 'comedy', it will give the the relevant films. How can I go about implementing this? Currently, the search is limited to the film's text and description.
I would appreciate if you give references to relevant resources or tutorials. Thanks
